# Image not Centering when using a class identifier

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to center an image using a class identifier in css. This should be a very simple exercise. So I am pretty sure the solution should be simple. img.center doesn't work either. Only way I have successfully gotten my image to center is with img only but I don't want all images to center. I've seen in several posts about the same topic that text-align: center should work. But that doesn't work either, tried display: inline in the img element too.

CSS

```
.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Family Obsession</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet'      type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class:"center">
    <img src="http://www.mariahswind.com/stitch-wiki/bigtree.png" alt="bigtree" class:"center">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div class:"center">` should be `<div class="center">`

Comment: @andrex I knew it had to be something sickenly stupid on my part! Thank you! How obvious that is now that you point it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on your `<div>` and `<img>` part. You have set you class incorrectly. It should be `<div class = "center">` and `<img class = "center">`

Answer (score 1):

The `margin-left:auto` (and -right) applies to the element it's self, so in this case to the `div` as well as the `img`.

The `text-align:center` declaration only works for the content inside that element. So using that on the CSS of the `div` would do the trick, as long as the `div` has the correct `width` set (for example `100%`).

Also it could be that parent elements create a `float` of their content, which might stop the `margin-left:auto` centering method.